# What is this text message, and how worried should I be?

Tags: iphone, sms, spam

The following text message popped up on my iPhone, and it doesn't seem to be coming from the Message app or any other apps on the phone. Obviously this is a spam. But which app is showing this message, and how worried should I be?

(I am listening to a podcast in Downcast app when the message appeared.)

[image: Screenshot of message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: The previous answer is wrong. Correct answer is the message is from the service provider. Thanks to @duci9y for the correction.

Comment: I doubt it's coming from Downcast. Pressing the home button didn't dismiss the app nor the message.

Comment: Woah! This is not an alert view. It's a service provider message. Same as the ones you get on prepaid phones to check your account balance.

Comment: If that's the case, then @Heng-CheongLeong you've been spammed by SingTel.

Comment: That's a first.

Comment: SingTel (the telco) currently pushes its own advertisements through SMS messages. This seems unusual as this is not normally how SingTel pushes advertisement, and that the message doesn't seem to be a typical SingTel advertisement. Can third-parties (i.e. somebody other than SingTel) send such a message, or is SingTel being hacked, or is my phone been hacked?

Comment: In the case of SingTel, unlikely given their competent reputation.